# Range with blank cells copy and pasted into single column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy and paste a range that includes blank cells into a single column on another sheet. I would like the blanks to be ignored.

Here is the Frankenstein code I am using at the moment it is slow and a bit cluncky  [picture included to better describe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YybeA.gif)

I would like to expand on it so that multiple ranges can paste into the same column ie find the last cell with a value and paste into the next cell.

i have been told it should look something like this

```
            'for r = 1 to 4
            '   for c = 1 to 8
            '       does rc have val,
            '           then copy to new sheet
            '           increment copy var
            '       increment c
            '     increment r


 Sheets(Array("next record date")).Select
Range("G11:AZZ110").Select
If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then
    If Selection.Count > 1 Then
        If Selection.Count <= Selection.Parent.Rows.Count Then
            vaCells = Selection.Value

            ReDim vOutput(1 To UBound(vaCells, 1) * UBound(vaCells, 2), 1 To 1)

            For j = LBound(vaCells, 2) To UBound(vaCells, 2)
                For i = LBound(vaCells, 1) To UBound(vaCells, 1)
                    If Len(vaCells(i, j)) > 0 Then
                        lRow = lRow + 1
                        Sheets("Data").Select
                        Range("E2").Select
                        vOutput(lRow, 1) = vaCells(i, j)
                        Else
                End If
            Next i
        Next j

            Selection.ClearContents
            Selection.Cells(1).Resize(lRow).Value = vOutput
    End If
End If
```

End If

Thanks,

Jerome

Comment: Hi, Image of your source data and the desired output would be helpful. And don't use .select. You will be able to use a With statement and also you don't really need sheet Array if copying from only one sheet (though that may be me being picky). Also, why If TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then? You have just selected the Range. Is it possible for some reason you cannot select it?

Answer (score 0):

Special cells constants method and paste transpose

```
Public Sub TransposeRange()

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("next record date").Range("G11:AZ11").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Range("E2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello, I have been using the code you have me and realized my life could be a lot easier if i combined some of m coulmns this means I have to find the last cell in the column and paste in the next cell, this is the code I came up with but I'm getting an error   
`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data base").Range(Worksheets("data base").Cells("G1").End(xlDown)).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=True` @QHarr

Comment: Check your syntax. You have ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data base").Range(Worksheets("data base").Cells("G1")   which is wrong. This should be something like ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data base").Range("G1")

Comment: Also i can't see where your paste range is defined

Comment: I made the change you suggested and put in a select so it now looks like this`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data base").Range("G1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=True` but I am still getting an Application-defined or object -defined error

Comment: Review the syntax for Copy Paste in VBA. You don't need .Select and you do need to specify a paste destination. See some examples here: https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/copy-paste-cells-vba-macros/

Comment: I know I don't but for the life of me I cant get it to work so I am trying any/everything

Comment: That's ok. I don't know what your new code is so you may need to post as a new question (provided it is not a duplicate of this one) . I don't know the full etiquette for SO but i suspect if this is an extended debugging of existing code it should continue in chat. There will be a prompt that should appear soon to enable this conversation to be moved to chat

Comment: It wont allow me to chat.  the latest version of my little code is `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data base").Range("G1").End(xlDown).Select.Offset(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Transpose:=True` i added the select back at a diffrent place and this got rid of the  Application-defined or object -defined error but now it brings me to the last possible cell and now i have an Object required error. I can ask another question if you think that is best practice.

Comment: End(xlDown) will not select the last populated cell if there are any blank cell in the range. You should try recording a macro whilst performing the necessary steps and see what the code looks like that is produced. An abridged version has the form Range("G1:G5").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")         There is a space between Copy and then next bit of text. I didn't type out the argument Destination:= in my original answer , but it is implied by position, so general form is myRange.copy [single space] Desination:= myPasteDestination

Comment: actually the original code doesn't work for selecting a range and putting it into a single column. It ends up scattering the data across multiple columns.     up till now I have been working with single row range so i didn't see the problem.

Comment: Original code had a single row, the code worked as it transposed one row into one column. That is as per the range you specified. If you changed the requirements you may have ended up with spread out values.

Comment: the original code would take all values in `Sheets(Array("next record date")).Select Range("G11:AZZ11").Select` and paste it ignoring any empty cells into ` Sheets("Data").Select Range("E2").Select`

Comment: G11:AZ11  is one row in height

Comment: ah shit I messed that up i use this same bit of code a lot and i must have picked one that only references one row. sorry.

Comment: That's ok. With Transpose: The transpose of an array is created by using the first row of the array as the first column of the new array, the second row of the array as the second column of the new array, and so on. That's from the documentation.

Comment: Yes, I am sure that is why i started using that original code to begin with. again sorry for the confusion I just really wanted it to be right.the code you suggested has made my life easier for the single row ranges i was working with.

Comment: Hi, you have unaccepted an answer that met the example you gave. Please edit your question if this is the case so others will be able to help with the redefined problem.